# Sandbox test accounts working at all?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create Sandbox accounts and many times it says there are issue creating my account, other times it creates but it is unverified... (both cloning the 2 pre-created accounts or creating brand new ones).

Am I doing anything wrong? I need them verified to avoid limits and stuff... and obviously, I won't go through a verification process for a test account.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.

You need a paypal account, with your real paypal account you log into the developers sandbox. There you can create test apps and users

Comment: I do have a paypal account and there are already 2 test accounts auto-created, but I want to create 2 more (one business one personal). I did that in the past with no problem, but now, there are issue and the only time I got them created, they are unverified...

Comment: The question you asked isnt very clear.. Honestly i dont know then, cause i just duplicated both my personal and business accounts, with no issues. 

Think this a question for paypal support. But before then you should ask yourself why bother duplicating the accounts.

Comment: because I need all the balances in the accounts reset, and there is no way to reset them.

Comment: Still, I cannot make verified test accounts... the site is throwing errors in many cases, and when it gets created, it is unverified and shows nothing in "Balance:". Seriously PayPal??

Comment: Yes, sometimes i observed also  https://developer.paypal.com throws error. Keep trying multiple times logout , login etc. It worked for me like that. When you are duplicating account you can mention the balance amount.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault, I also noticed the sandbox environment / developer dashboard / account creation process are full of errors.

Some hints:

1. Don't create test account using the developer dashboard, create directly from www.sandbox.paypal.com and add it to dashboard by clicking the link in "Want to link existing Sandbox Account with your developer account? Click Here and provide credentials of your sandbox account"
2. As it's a sandbox account, it won't send email to your real email address, instead, after you did Step 1, you can click on the sandbox test account list in developer dashboard, and access the "notifications". Which list the "emails" paypal sent. Be warned most of the emails are garbage as they are based64 encoded HTML, decoding them shows incomplete HTML code. You may try to setup your paypal account so that notification are sent in plain text, not HTML. You will need these email to get your account verified.
3. Even if your account has no money, try to send some and it should automatically create some for you.