# how to customize credit card payment in paypal

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card

i have done payment though sandbox.Paypal account and i have created separate menu for credit card payment
i have created separate menu for credit-card payment

[image]
after user filling these details i don't want to show Paypal page .it has to check details in Paypal and redirects to success.php  but m not getting how to do that. can any one please let me know?

here with the dodirectpayment processs

```
<div class="btn btn-primary">
<form method="post" action="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp">
<input type="hidden" name="USER" value="username"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PWD" value="password"/>
<input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="api signature"/>
<input type="hidden" name="METHOD" value="DoDirectPayment"/>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTACTION" value="Authorization"/>
<input type="hidden" name="IPADDRESS" value="192.168.1.12"/>
<input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="86.0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CREDITCARDTYPE" value="VISA"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ACCT" value="4641631486853053"/>
<input type="hidden" name="EXPDATE" value="052015"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CVV2" value="123"/>
<input type="hidden" name="AMT" value="23.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CURRENCYCODE" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="FIRSTNAME" value="James"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LASTNAME" value="smith"/>
<input type="hidden" name="STREET" value="firstStreet"/>
<input type="hidden" name="CITY" value="SanJose"/>
<input type="hidden" name="STATE" value="CA"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Zip" value="95131"/>
<input type="hidden" name="COUNTRYCODE" value="US"/>
<button class="btn">pay 2</button>
</form>
</div>

             Result:TIMESTAMP=2016%2d01%2d19T07%3a49%3a33Z&CORRELATIONID=8e30307764193&ACK=Failure&VERSION=86%2e0&BUILD=18308778&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Errorstrong text
```

i have done Paypal in others menu and i need separate credit/debit payment using Paypal for checking details but with out showing Paypal page

Comment: why would you dont want to show paypal page? for me showing paypal page is kinda feel secured. Will never ever transact that says it is paypal but address is different, interface is different and not even https

Comment: i have done Paypal in others menu and i created separate page for credit/debit payment in this i have to use Paypal (for checking details) but i want done without showing Paypal page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what your trying to do, is a paypal NVP authorization and capture. By posting a form to paypal you will not get the result your looking for.

What you need to do is a Direct Payment Using NVP and cURL

You will find more about it 
@https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDPGettingStarted/

Look under the section titled "Implementing the Simplest Direct Payment Integration"

Note**
 i recommend paypals SDK instead. For what your trying to achieve look how easy in comparsion this example is 
@https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePayment.php

Comment: Thank you :) and one more thing  i tried to create US sandbox account from developer console but continuously i am getting this error  ** "we are sorry ,something went wrong during account creation.try again later" **   whats wrong?

Comment: Thats a different issue, not sure what thats about, this guy had same issue sort of issue..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854451/sandbox-test-accounts-working-at-all/34854571?noredirect=1#comment57451919_34854571

Make sure its your live paypal account your signing in with and make sure create a test app

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered, if your first problem has been solved :)

Comment: Thank you so much Gomes :)  I Got Success Acknowledgement  ACK=Success

Comment: 404 not found for the links.